# Apache .htaccess rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

this is what I want to achieve.

I want to rewrite this  url
http://example.com?page=something
to this
http://example.com/something

such that i can $_GET whatever is after the url
$_GET['page']= 'something'

all the tutorials I've read show it like http: //example.com/page /something
so i was wondering if it is possible without the extra "/"

//Update

this is what i have on the.httaccess file

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

but when i do a echo($_GET['page'] ); i get index.php

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Many of the exact duplicates we have on this explain that case. Please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteRule ^something/?$ /something.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to accept a parameter though

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```