# apache htaccess map first segment as parameter without disturbing other parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is might be a classic .htaccess question, but still I couldn't find the question for my specific case. Here's the [closest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299793/apache-httaccess-rewriting) I found (parameters involve in my case). Done implementing the two answers. Couldn't work for my case.

**My case**

1) I want any access for this URL,

```
mywebsite.com/any-first-segment?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c&paramN=anything
```

will be remapped to

```
mywebsite.com/index.php?p=any-first-segment&param1=a&param2=b&param3=c&paramN=anything
```

2) Still working if there's no param.

3) I will never have more than one segment. (zero segment still works, mapped to index.php as usual)

---

Could you suggest me the working RewriteRule for this case?

Here's the last .htaccess, which is still not working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

[Updated!]
It's working. I found I messed up with `Options +FollowSymLinks` after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829877/htaccess-code-to-set-qsa-for-all-redirects-automatically-globally)

Here's the working .htaccess. With exception.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [`QSA` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) in your rule will append the current query string to the rewritten form.

Comment: Here I found after googling. You mean this? RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: I change my .htaccess to try and still not working, 500 internal server error. here is mine. `RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Ups, forget about RewriteCond `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]` still not work... :(

Comment: Okay. I messed up with `Options +FollowSymLinks` & RewriteCond